# Error request for member '.......' in '......', which is of non-class type '.....'

Tags: c++, sorting, bubble-sort

```
for(i=0;i<x;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<i;j++)
    {
        if(bor.hasil[i]<bor.hasil[j])
        {
            bor.n[i].swap (bor.hasil[j]);
            
            tmp=bor.hasil[i];
            bor.hasil[i]=bor.hasil[j];
            bor.hasil[j]=tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

how to fix error request for member 'swap' in 'bor.tes::n[i]', which is of non-class type 'char'?

Comment: Does it have a `swap` function?

Comment: The code and diagnostic presented do not seem to go together.  There is no `bor.tes` in the code presented.

Comment: Please provide [mre].

Comment: @JohnBollinger whats the mean ?

Comment: The error is about some line that contains `'bor.tes::n[i]`, but you don't have such a line in your code. Maybe a typo? Please post a piece of code that we can copy into an ide and run _without any further modification_ to reproduce the error you get. And secondly please post (copy-paste) the _exact_ error message as text.

Comment: @ChristianLie, the diagnostic message you presented, "request for member 'swap' in 'bor.tes::n[i]', which is of non-class type 'char'", refers to an object identified by "bor.tes::n[i]".  There is a `bor` in your code, but not a `bor.tes` or a `bor.tes.n`, so the message does not seem to be referring to the code you presented.

Comment: Judging by your other question, should `bor.n[i].swap (bor.hasil[j]);` maybe be `std::swap(bor.hasil[i], bor.hasil[j]);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to fix error request for member 'swap' in 'bor.tes::n[i]', which is of non-class type 'char'?

Although it seems not to go with the code presented in the question, the diagnostic is relatively clear.  It is complaining about an attempt to invoke a method named `swap()` on the object designated by `bor.tes::n[i]`.  That is unacceptable because the type of `bor.tes::n[i]` is `char`, which not only does not have any methods named `swap()`, but which, not being a class type, does not have any methods *at all*.

You need to come up with another way to perform the operation you want, such as perhaps `std::swap`:

```
// swap the values of x and y, provided that x is move-assignable and move-constructible
// and that y is swappable
std::swap(x, y);
```

or there's always a good, old-fashioned three-way swap using a temporary:

```
// swap the values of chars x and y:
char tmp = x;
x = y;
y = tmp;
```

Comment: Thank You very much, its work !

Comment: The first line probably should have been `std::swap(bor.hasil[i], bor.hasil[j]);`?

Comment: @churill, I am not inclined to guess at what the OP's actual code was.  The code presented mixes `bor.n` and `bor.hasil`, which is suspicious in itself, and the error message they present refers to something else again.  `std::swap()` would probably be more idiomatic than the old-fashioned swap I offered, but depending on the details, it might be that *neither* of those is viable for the OP's true purpose.  The main point of this answer is to explain the diagnostic.

Comment: @JohnBollinger That's right of course, no critic there :) Just wanted to mention it, since OP's last question was also aimed at something like this, where someone suggested to use `std::swap` instead.